# How to put special character between string

Tags: python

I have a string like `"0013A200305EFF96"`. I want to change it to be in form `"\x00\x13\xA2\x00\x30\x5E\xFF\x96"`. The special character is `"\x"`. How can I do this in  a time efficient way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Python2

```
>>> "0013A200305EFF96".decode("hex")
'\x00\x13\xa2\x000^\xff\x96'
```

### Python3

```
>>> bytes.fromhex("0013A200305EFF96")
b'\x00\x13\xa2\x000^\xff\x96'
```

Comment: what is this ^in results

Comment: You want to escape the printable characters too?

Comment: result should be also in form of string

Comment: So the \ are literal?

Answer (score 1):

gnibbler's answer is probably what you are *really* looking for; but for completeness, here is how you can insert any sequence:

```
>>> '\\x'.join(a[i:i+2] for i in xrange(0, len(a), 2))
```

Comment: can I change the results in form of hex value if I want namely results will be '\x00\x13\xA2\x00\x30\x5E\xFF\x96'

Answer (score 1):

If you mean literal `\x`:

```
import re
s= "0013A200305EFF96"
s=re.sub("(..)", r"\x\1",s)
print s
```

**Output**

```
\x00\x13\xA2\x00\x30\x5E\xFF\x96
```

Comment: Can I ask one question, If I have "\x12" as a string, how can I convert it to be hex value, its type, and value is '\x12' ?